# Tooltip that displays dynamic list of names in a gridview item template label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that is loading dynamic data into an item template label, with the ultimate goal being for every message loaded into the gridview, there is a column called "recipients" that has a count of the recipients. I want a tooltip to display the list of names of every recipient for that message. The data I want to get at for the tooltip is in a list within another list. I'm trying to use the following data binding tag:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblRecipients" runat="server" Text="recipients" ToolTip='<%# Eval("Recipients.fullName") %>'></asp:Label>
```

With Recipients being a list within this object:

```
[DataContract]
public class Message
{
    [DataMember]
    public string MsgId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MsgSize { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DateRecorded { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ActiveDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal RecordTime { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long Filelength { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Person { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Person> Recipients { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int RecipientCount { get; set; }
}
```

When I debug, I get the following message on the Eval:

```
HttpException was unhandled by user code.

DataBinding: 'Share.Service.Person[]' does not contain a property with the name 'FullName'.
```

Even though when I run my WCF Test client, I see that at that point, it is populating the FullName property in each Person object with the recipients names. I'm not exactly too sure how to tackle this challenge at the moment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can bind the data like this, the message is correct, there is no property with "FullName" in the Receipients, (Person[])

How about you have a formatting function like

```
protected string GetFullNames(List<Person> persons) {
    // do whatever you want and return the formatted string
}
```

and then you bind your tooltip to that function output?

```
<asp:Label ID="lblRecipients" runat="server" Text="recipients" ToolTip='<%= GetFullNames(Recipients) %>'></asp:Label>
```